# Android: discard events perceived after a button click

Tags: android, events, button, event-handling

At the push of a button the application tries to send a data to a server. If the connection is active, the data is immediately sent, but if the link is down, the system attempts to send for x seconds. In fact, in that period of time, the interface is (intentionally) blocked (the button is illuminated to highlight the current operation). The problem is that if the user starts to press other buttons, the events are heard and when the connection becomes active, it performs all the operations related to those events.
How can I prevent it?
How to prevent that How to prevent each event related to other buttons to be processed?
Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**
I've already tried to check a flag when the button is pressed, unfortunately when the flag is re-setted, all events are catched and executed:

```
public void onClick(View v) {                   
    switch(v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.button1:  //when sendData() is trying to send the message, I don't want to that this code is executed
       if(flagConf  == 1)  
       {
                ...do something...
       }
       break;
    case R.id.buttonConfirm:

        if(myFlag  == 1)    //to avoid multiple touch of this button
        {
            ...do something...
            myFlag = 0;
            sendData(); 
            if(dataSent)     
             ...do something...
            else
            ...do something...
            myFlag = 1;  //I set this flag to 1 because, if message is not sent, the user have to re-pressed the buttonConfirm and try again
        }     
     break;
    }
 }
```

And on other button listeners:

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a flag that is set to something like `boolean = true;` while the data is processing. Then check in each `Button` in the `onClick`

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
     if (!sending)
     {
         // do stuff
     }
}
```

if `sending` is `true` then the `Button` will do nothing. Remember to set the `flag` back to `false` when you are done processing your data or whatever. You also could use buttonName.setEnabled(false);`then back to`true` after after you are done.

**Side Note:** if this operation takes very long at all (maybe more than a second or two), I would discourage against not allowing them to do anything as people have become very impatient creatures. No one wants to sit and look at a spinning circle for several seconds. However, if you choose to do this then you may want to show some message so they know why the `Buttons` aren't working

Comment: Unfortunately I've already done this, but all other events are catched... When the connection turns on all the events are processed.

Comment: Hmmm...that doesn't make sense unless there's something else going on in your code. You've tried the above inside an `onClick` and the code still runs? If this is the case then you may want to post some of the code so we can see exactly what's going on

Comment: From just that code, it looks like `myFlag ` is being set to 1 no matter what the result of dataSent. You should be setting that only after your `sendData()` method executes successfully

Comment: Yes, I set myFlag to 1 because if the message was not sent, the user has to press the button trying to send it another time.

Comment: And that's ok, you just want the other `Button`s disabled? What is `flagConf` and where is that set? If you set a breakpoint there and it == 1 then it won't run that code. Maybe I am not understanding you

Comment: I've tried to edit my answer. I set that flag to 1 because the user if the message was not sent, has to re-press buttonConfirm, but buttonConfirm is also protect with the if(myFlag == 1) test and if I don't reset it to 1, the user can't try again.

Comment: So use a separate `flag` to check for the other `Button`s and don't reset that one until after the data is sent, you are done trying, or whenever you want the `Button`s enabled again

Comment: What a mess...today has been a looong day ;) Thank you very much (+1 and accepted answer).

Comment: I know those days all to well ;) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. And there's a nice and neat way to solve that.

My connections to the server was done through a class that extended `AsyncTask`. That way, every time I pressed the button, I would check if the task was running. If it wasn't, it would generate a new task and would execute that.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (updateThread == null){

        updateThread = new UpdateThreadClass();
        updateThread.execute();
    }
}
```

Then create the AsyncTask like:

```
   public class UpdateThreadsClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Your code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        // Execute after completing the connection
    }
}
```

Declare the variable `updateThread` as global then your good to go.

If you want, you can either activate a progressive bar on your `XML` by changing the visibility ( `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` or `.setVisibility(View.Gone)` inside the `onClick` )before and after the task is done, or you can can do the same for the button.

**Edit**

You can put the progressive bar in the `XML` like so:

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading_screen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Then after clicking the button, just do like `loadingScreen = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading_screen)` and set the visibility VISIBLE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't use an AsyncTask. If I don't use it, can I add the progressive bar?

Comment: Yes, you can! Let me edit the answer and I'll add the snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much, good hint. I've already accepted an answer so I give you a +1.